# IOCP file limit on AIX 7.1

Tags: aix, aio

I am seeing E_BADF returned from aio_read/aio_write operations against FD 192 when the application is accessing a large number of files through a common IOCP.

Is there a limit to the number of files descriptors that can be associated with a simple IO Completion port under AIX 7.1? Can the limit be raised? Is there a reason to limit the number of file descriptors per IOCP?

ulimit reports an unlimited number of file descriptors, so that's not it. I'm hoping there is another tunable.

Thanks.

Comment: AIO isn't IOCP, IOCP is exclusive to NT Kernel AFAIK

Comment: Also please show us the code that isn't working, more than likely you're already working on a closed file descriptor for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The errors turned out to arise from un-related coding issues from a parallel set of potential changes (read: I'm an idiot).

For what it's worth, though, AIX does support an implementation of IOCP when you enable legacy AIO support.